# Generate Unique Employee code in String

Tags: java, mysql, unique-key

I am implementing Employee Management System in Java. I want employee code to be auto generated on new employee registration and I should be in predefined format. I don't want to use auto incremented integer key as a employee ID. I am using MySQL Database and JDBC API to connect to MySQL. Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: DB ... autoincrement.

Comment: Use a ``UUID``.

Comment: You could consider using a timestamp or randomly generated sequence as an id

Comment: TimeStamp or time in ticks should work

Comment: @sshashank124 neither of which would be guaranteed unique.

Comment: "should be in predefined format" — _what_ format?

Comment: Like company employee name Initials, Joining Year and Date of birth

Comment: @NileshDeshmukh if that is the format you have to use, what are you asking about? but I hope you understand that none of this guarantees there won't be duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the ID does not matter just use java.util.UUID to generate a universally unique identifier.

Comment: I want to keep length short

Comment: @NileshDeshmukh if you keep it short, you seriously minimize the number of possible users

Comment: Okay...Thanks @Stultuske

Comment: @Stultuske if he uses a random sequence of numbers and letters then even a length of 5 would give him 36^5=60466176 possibilities. How likely is it that a person who has to ask how to generate a random string will have more than 60million users registered in his software?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I've nowhere seen he intends to use 'numbers and letters'. You are assuming one thing, I'm assuming another. for all I know, all he wants to use are the numbers 1 through 5

Answer (score 0):

There can be many approaches to generate an employee Id.I am recommending following most commonly used methods.

1) **Timestamp Based** :- Use UUID from java.util.UUID to generate random ID's based on host and current time.

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
```

2) **Custom Information Based**

If you want an employeeId to be generated using Company Initials/Employee's Personal Information,

- Use employee's username and date of birth
- Take a namespace identifier(can be your organisation's name)

  With the hash of unique identifier and username of employee,

  ```
  String source = namespace + username + dateofbirth;
  byte[] bytes = source.getBytes("UTF-8");
  UUID uuid = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(bytes);
  ```

3) **Use Company Initials** :
   Lets say your company initials are XYZ.Use a random number generator function to generate any 5 or 6 digit number.
  Eg. XYZ47899